# Can we reopen "Did Jeffry Epstein kill himself?"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

It has been a minute. This controversial question here:
[Did Jeffry Epstein kill himself?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/did-jeffry-epstein-kill-himself)

Is nearly three years old, and is beginning to be forgotten about. Before that happens, and before things become murkier and murkier and prominent details begin to fade or be paved over, I think the question deserves to be re-opened.

Comment: What new information would you like to add to that question? As far as I am aware the information around that question hasn't really changed over the years.

Answer (score 3):

I have re-opened the question because, purely as a point of order, I think you are right. Sufficient time has passed that this is no longer a "current event".

However, I posted a comment on the original question which I think is still worth considering:

> What are you hoping to achieve with this question? You know what the Chief Medical Examiner officially concluded. You know that many people don't believe it. Do you think a ragtag bunch of Skeptics.SE denizens are going to reexamine the evidence that many journalists, activists and experts have already heavily scrutinised, and blow this case wide open? That's not how we work. Pretty much the only answer you can get here is what you already know.

The Wikipedia page (which I have now linked in for context) pretty much covers the arguments from both sides. There is not a lot more for us to add here.

Comment: `Do you think a ragtag bunch of Skeptics.SE denizens are going to reexamine the evidence` TBF, it was a rag tag journalist who was responsible for getting Epstein arrested in the first place, and brought to light an enormous amount of fishy dealings with his past legal history. As to the wikipedia article, I can almost say with certainty that it does not cover both sides fairly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320109/has-or-does-se-suffer-from-shills-or-cabals-of-special-interest-groups-looking-t -- Given any severe political implications, wikipedia quickly becomes counter-reliable.

Comment: @Anon: I do not know which journalist you are referring to. Could you provide a link? If you are coming into this with the attitude that the Wikipedia page, which spends hundreds of words covering the conspiracy theories and their support with references, doesn't adequately cover the topic, then I caution you that answering this question is going to be very difficult. Personal incredulity and anomaly hunting won't be sufficient. Any evidence for homicide will have to be much stronger than any we have seen so far.

Comment: Re `Which journalist` That would be Mike Cernovich. https://www.cernovich.com/epstein/ See: `I filed a lawsuit to unseal documents involving a sex trafficking lawsuit that had been brought against a billionaire. The Second Circuit Court of Appeals heard oral argument in our case.`

Comment: `Personal incredulity and anomaly hunting won't be sufficient.` Its far more complicated, as what epistemelogical standards a person chooses [ And for what end ], is a deeply personal and subjective affair. Some people do better appealing to authorities, while others falter spectacularly. What matters in terms of sufficiency, is that their method chosen has become more sufficient than any other at their disposal, and that they apply it consistently.

Comment: @Anon: Welcome to Skeptics.SE, where we have our own shared epistemological standards: scientific skepticism.

Comment: @Anon: So that is blogger, Mike Cernovich... in combination with Professor Alan Dershowitz and the Miami Herald, who, combined, had the resources to fund a court case that went to the  Second Circuit Court of Appeals - rather more resources that a poster here, which is exactly my point - we can't do what journalists backed by newspapers, and law-enforcement officers backed by the government can do. (Note: Cernovich wasn't involved with "getting Epstein arrested in the first place". Epstein was first convicted in 2008. Cernovich started legal proceedings in 2017.)

Comment: re: `Scientific Skepticism` What the SE chooses to use, is up to that which makes up the SE. I personally advocate away from this methodological monism, especially within the realm of human affairs. I think it is kind of ludicrous for example to conclude in here https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/34906/30694 that `In summary there's no evidence that points to Seth being the source,` because Assange wouldnt go on the record. That "scientific skepticism" completely divorces teleology from consideration, because if it didn't, it would have to admit that obviously that Seth Rich was the leaker

Comment: @Anon: Then this site is clearly not for you. Thanks for stopping by. No-one should attempt to answer the Epstein question here without adhering to scientific skepticism.

Comment: `No-one should attempt to answer the Epstein question here without adhering to scientific skepticism.` The consequences being what exactly?

Comment: Deletion of the post and, if a user is insistent on ignoring the standards required, suspension, are the consequences.

Comment: I think "we should mindlessly believe the state" is an insane attitude for a site about Skepticism.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim: Indeed. Which is why no-one has expressed that view.